# Spring Boot Kotlin data class not initailized with default values in REST controller

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, data-class

I have started migrating a Spring Boot application from Java to Kotlin. Before, everything worked perfectly. Now I can't update any Entity received through PUT/POST, because the data doesn't contain the default values from the data class

One entity looks like that:

```kotlin
package org.some.soft.domain

import java.util.*
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "book_item")
data class BookItem (

    @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH])
    var book: Book,

    @Column(name = "format", nullable = false)
    var format: BookFormat = BookFormat.HARDCOVER,

    @Column(name = "barcode", nullable = false)
    var barcode: String = "0000000000000",

    @Column(name = "label", unique = true)
    var label: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "isReferenceOnly", nullable = false)
    var referenceOnly: Boolean = false,

    @Column(name = "borrowed")
    var borrowed: Date? = null,

    @Column(name = "dueDate")
    var dueDate: Date? = null,

    @Column(name = "price")
    var price: Double? = null,

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    var status: BookStatus = BookStatus.AVAILABLE,

    @Column(name = "dateOfPurchase")
    var dateOfPurchase: Date = Date(),

    @Column(name = "publicationDate", nullable = false)
    var publicationDate: Date = Date(),

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    var id: Long? = null,
)
```

I receive the data through following controller:

```kotlin
    @PutMapping("/book/items")
    fun updateBookItem(@RequestBody book: @Valid BookItem): ResponseEntity<BookItem> {
        val result = bookService.updateBook(book)
        return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert(applicationName, true, ENTITY_NAME, book.id.toString()))
            .body(result)
    }
```

The service just calls the save method from JPA-Repository (`bookItemRepository.save(bookItem)`) and that's the step where I get the following error:

```
NULL not allowed for column "PUBLICATION_DATE"; SQL statement:
update book_item set barcode=?, book_id=?, borrowed=?, date_of_purchase=?, due_date=?, format=?, label=?, price=?, publication_date=?, is_reference_only=?, status=? where id=? [23502-214]
```

Following [this](https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/best-practices-and-common-pitfalls/) tutorial and by copying gradle build from another JHipster project I added the following plugins:

```
apply plugin: "kotlin" // Required for Kotlin integration
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt" // Required for annotations processing
apply plugin: "kotlin-spring" // See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#spring-support
apply plugin: "kotlin-allopen" // See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#using-in-gradle
apply plugin: "kotlin-jpa" // See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#jpa-support
apply plugin: "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt"

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlin_version}"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlin_version}"


    kapt "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}"
    kapt "org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:${hibernateVersion}"
    kapt "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:${jaxbRuntimeVersion}"

    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:${kotlin_version}"

    testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0"
}

allOpen {
    annotation("javax.persistence.Entity")
    annotation("javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass")
    annotation("javax.persistence.Embeddable")
}
```

But still I get the issue indicating me, that Spring Boot isn't using my default values from data class. I also debugged, and the attributes are not initialized with their default values.

I also tried changing `var` to `val` but the error still persists

Note: I do not send the null values from the client. My request body only contains values that are not `null`

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: What does the request body that you pass to `/book/items` look like?

Comment: The default values you're giving are for calls directly from Kotlin, which allows you to omit parameters (and giving explicit names for any later params). I'm not sure Spring knows about them. I'd suggest trying to add a Spring annotation which lets you specify a default value, such as `@ApiParam`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with a few combinations, I finally found the problem.

JPA uses the no-arg constructor generated by the Gradle plugin by default. When setting default values, the primary constructor has to be a no-arg constructor, which means all parameters have to be optional, so it gets used by JPA.

Here is what I changed: (I set null as default for book and added the `@NotNull` annotation)

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "book_item")
data class BookItem (

    @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH])
    @NotNull
    var book: Book? = null,

    @Column(name = "format", nullable = false)
    var format: BookFormat = BookFormat.HARDCOVER,

    @Column(name = "barcode", nullable = false)
    var barcode: String = "0000000000000",

    @Column(name = "label", unique = true)
    var label: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "isReferenceOnly", nullable = false)
    var referenceOnly: Boolean = false,

    @Column(name = "borrowed")
    var borrowed: Date? = null,

    @Column(name = "dueDate")
    var dueDate: Date? = null,

    @Column(name = "price")
    var price: Double? = null,

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    var status: BookStatus = BookStatus.AVAILABLE,

    @Column(name = "dateOfPurchase")
    var dateOfPurchase: Date = Date(),

    @Column(name = "publicationDate", nullable = false)
    var publicationDate: Date = Date(),

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    var id: Long? = null,
)
```

This solved all my problems.

Comment: This may have solved your problems, but it is certainly not advisable as a general solution. This greatly increased the chances of bugs as someone could end up writing nullable/default values to the DB when they really are not wanted.